# Incorrect date returned when using new Date()

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

While using datebox with jquery mobile I want to set the textbox of the datefield with todays date. So I am using

//html

```
<input data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFieldOrder":["d","m","y"], "useNewStyle":true,"overrideDateFormat": "%d/%m/%Y", "afterToday":true}'  name="startDate" id="startDate" type="date" />
```

//JS

```
var defaultPickerValue = new Date();
var today = defaultPickerValue.getDate() + "/" + (defaultPickerValue.getMonth()+1) + "/" + defaultPickerValue.getFullYear();

$('#startDate').val(today);
$('#endDate').val(today);
```

This sets my date fields with todays date in `dd/mm/yy` format.

Now to calculate the difference of days between todays date and the date that I will choose in the calendar I am using :

```
var temp = new Date();
diff = parseInt((new Date($('#startDate').val()) - temp) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
```

But `new Date($('#startDate').val())` returns some incorrect date and does not calculates the difference correctly. For e.g if I select `31st may 2014` in calendar, `new Date($('#startDate').val())` returns

```
Tue Jul 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}**
```

Please help.

Comment: Strings passed to the `Date()` function must be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Read this for acceptable formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

Use Moment.js for Date Manipulation/Calculation/Differentiation. http://momentjs.com . You don't have to fight much.

Answer (score 0):

How bout using the datebox 'getTheDate' function?

```
var temp = new Date();
diff = parseInt(( $('#startDate').datebox('getTheDate').getTime() - temp.getTime() ) / (1000*60*60*24)),10);
```

If you are manually playing with $('#startDate').val(), you may want to throw a refresh in there first, to make sure datebox has read any new value.

```
$('#startDate').datebox('refresh');
```